# Asynchronous image loading in the background with javascript (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have an application form that shows an image on the left part and some input texts on the right part. The users will have to fill the input texts and click next to show the next image. The problem is that the images are big and it is taking a long time to load and it is time consuming.

What I want to do is when the user starts filling the form from the first image for example, I want to start downloading the next image with ajax asynchronously, by the time the user finishes working on the first image the next image will be downloaded to the client, and when the user clicks next, the browser will show the next image, and so on.

I tried this code but it is not working as I explained. The page is waiting until the both images are loaded then it is showing the first image, any help would be appreciated:

**HTML**

```
<img id="currentImage" src="currentImage.png" onload="currentImageLoad()"></img>
<img id="nextImage" style="display: none;"></img>
```

**Javascript**

```
function currentImageLoad(){
    $('#nextImage').attr('src' , 'nextImage.png');
}
```

Comment: [tag:JAVA] tag removed. Please let me know if I did this erroneously.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No its fine, I am using JSF, thats why I thought it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can lazy load the image using jquery unveil plugin.

> http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

Answer (score 0):

javascript is synchronous. You can delay the loading of the second image to prevent this:

```
function currentImageLoad(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#nextImage').attr('src' , 'nextImage.png');
    }, 10); // 10ms
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need, it's not complicated. JQuery is only used here for simplified selecting / DOM Manipulating.

```
<!-- click this button to append the image to #image-frame -->
<button id="append-image">append image</button>

<!-- image will go here -->
<div id="image-frame"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    // 1. create a image object and load the image file (this will display nowhere)
    var image_url = 'https://image.spreadshirtmedia.net/image-server/v1/compositions/123658308/views/1,width=300,height=300,version=1472099537/evil-maenner-premium-t-shirt.jpg',
        image = new Image();
    image.src = image_url;

    // 2. create a new <img> element and append to the frame
    // (the image will load from cache if the previous download is finished, or load from remote if it's not)
    $('#append-image').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<img src="'+image_url+'">').appendTo($('#image-frame'));
    });
});
</script>
```